# LINQ Extract partial match from dataTable from list

Tags: c#, vb.net, linq

I'm trying to extract all rows from a dataTable that for column "A" have at the end a string from a list.

For example:

DataTable

```
ID     A
1      1220
2      1221
3      1223
```

list

```
{"20","23"}
```

To return
**1   1220** and **3 1223**

```
(From x In dt.AsEnumerable() 
Where list.Any(Function(l) l.EndsWith(x("number").ToString))
Select x).CopyToDataTable
```

This is what I've come up so far but it only extracts a row if there is a full match in the list, say **12220**, for **20** it doesn't return anything.

Can you help ?

Comment: i think it should be x.ToString().EndsWith(l) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You tagged your question with `C#`. In C# the query would be

```
dataTable
    .Where(r => list.Any(s => r.A.EndsWith(s)))
```

The test code I tried is

```
var array = dataSet1
    .DataTable1
    .Where(r => list.Any(s => r.A.EndsWith(s)))
    .ToArray();
```

Where dataSet1 is a strongly typed dataset and DataTable1 is a table with columns `Id` and `A`